# "zsh: command not found: eslint" (and other commands installed via npm)

Tags: node.js, npm

I just reset my Macbook and am getting "command not found" after installing packages via npm.

I have a working install of `npm` and `node` on my machine:

```
$ node -v
v18.9.0

$ npm -v
8.19.1
```

I've used `npm install` within my project directory, and can see the `node_modules` folder with the associated commands.

However, when I run something like `eslint`, I get:

```
$ eslint 
zsh: command not found: eslint
```

My path is up-to-date:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I'm assuming that my machine isn't able to find the installed packages, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You mean _locally_ installed in that package? Use NPX, or scripts in the package file, or reference the executables directory `node_modules/.bin/`.

Answer (score 2):

In project folder run:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init
```

<kbd>[about this - github](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10192)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

For `eslint` to be recognized as a command, you need to have it in the `PATH` and one way to do this is to install the package globally. Which means that running the command will run the package installed globally and not the local one.

If you want to use the package from your local node_modules folder, you need to run it with `npx eslint`. You could also define an alias in the `package.json` to run it with `npm run eslint`.

One last possible solution would be to add the path `node_modules/.bin` to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in their answers, I was installing packages locally, and I would need to use `npx` in order to use them.

For this particular project, I am installing `eslint` to use for syntax checking within Emacs.

For this reason, it makes more sense to install `eslint` globally to make it easier for Emacs to find the executable, e.g. `npm install -g eslint`.

I've done this and it's fixed the problem I was having.